# Prove that if $F$ is a family of sets and $A\in F$, then $\bigcap F\subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Question is from "How to Prove it" by Vellenman.
I am struggling to even understand how this theorem could ever be true?

I get that the first step is to assume x is an arbitrary element of $\bigcap F$, as the definition of $\bigcap F\subseteq A$ breaks down to $\forall x(x\in\bigcap F \rightarrow x\in A)$. Suppose $x\in \bigcap F$.

From here I am now confused about the definition of $\bigcap F$ and how $\bigcap F$ could even be a proper subset of $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A proof in Velleman's style would possibly look like this:

Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigcap\mathcal F$. From $x\in\bigcap\mathcal F$ and $A\in\mathcal F$ we obtain $x\in A$ $($by universal instantiation$)$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in\bigcap\mathcal F\rightarrow x\in A)$ and so $\bigcap\mathcal F\subseteq A$. $Q.E.D.$

Universal instantiation is well explained in the book.

Comment: Universal instantiation is only used as a proof strategy when you have a 'Given' that includes a Universal Quantifier? Where have you found a Universal Quantifier in the Givens

Comment: Exactly. You let $x$ be arbitrary and then you will have $x\in\bigcap\mathcal F$ in the givens. But $x\in\bigcap\mathcal F$ has a possibility for universal instantiation hidden in it $($if you open it up$)$.

Comment: I don't think that Universal Instantiation is needed though? If you have the definition of ⋂F, which I now understand that contains x∈A which we have classified as true. Therefore, where is the need for Universal Instantiation?

Comment: Wait, are you applying Universal Instantiation so that the definition for ⋂F applies in this case to set A?

Comment: @BlueSky Exactly.

Comment: Class, that make all sense now. Thank you very much

Comment: @BlueSky You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$\bigcap F$ is the set of all things that are members of **every** member of the family $F$: $$\forall x\left(x\in\bigcap F\leftrightarrow\forall S\in F(x\in S)\right)\;.$$

Suppose that $x\in\bigcap F$; then by definition $x\in S$ for every $S\in F$. In particular, $x\in A$, since $A\in F$. Thus, $\bigcap F\subseteq A$.

Comment: Hold on, to double check I understand. ⋂F means the elements within each set? For example: Say F = {1,2,3},{2} then ⋂F is {2} and not ∅

Comment: @BlueSky: If $F=\big\{\{1,2,3\},\{2\}\big\}$, then yes, $$\bigcap F=\{1,2,3\}\cap\{2\}=\{2\}\;.$$

Comment: Ahh, I thought that the entire set had to be the same. That is yet again an error on my part. Going to review my knowledge of families of sets then and come back to these answers

Comment: Yes, understanding of definition of intersection of F was wrong. That was why I did not understand the answer

Comment: @BlueSky: Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0):

I assume $\bigcap F $ means $\bigcap_{X\in F}X=:B$ and $A$ is an element in $F$.

Now take any $x\in B$, then it is in all $X$ from $F$ in paritculary in $A$.

Since $x$ was arbitrary we have $B\subseteq A$ and we are done.